# In astronomy, what is a 'reflex orbit'?

Tags: astronomy, orbital-motion, terminology

In astronomy, what is a [reflex orbit](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=reflex+orbit)? The term is used in one of my books, but u don't find a definition for it. Googling it gives me articles about 'Oculocardiac reflex' which is not what I want.

From the context it is something to do with how centre of mass can cause starts to wobble but I'm not certain of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this source](http://exoplanet.as.arizona.edu/~lclose/teaching/a202/lect19.html), ([and this one](http://www.astro.cornell.edu/academics/courses/astro1101/java/Finding%20Exosolar%20Planets.htm)), it's the "wobble" one can detect in nearby stars if they have an orbiting exoplanet - either detected directly or via Doppler shift of the star's spectrum.